# Regular ceiling fan switch to smart ceiling fan switch

Tags: lighting, switch, ceiling-fan

I have a "regular" ceiling fan/light combo switch that I am trying to switch out to a smart ceiling fan/light combo switch requiring a neutral. Once I connect all the wiring (following the old switch) the smart switch does not work. The LED indicator lights go on, but the lights and the fan do not work. There is a gang box directly behind it that has a different smart switch installed and works (separate line wires). There is a bundle of white wires in each box with a wire that goes between the two boxes. The "shared" wired must be used with the ceiling fan/light switch for the indicator lights to work on the switch. The ceiling fan has been up for 10+ years. Any idea why the fan or light won't work with the smart switch and only works with the regular switch?

Comment: How about some pictures of your switches , junction box and switch box.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of both the switch and fan boxes please?